# How to get the "title" instead of the "value" of a preference with getString()

Tags: java, android, arrays, eclipse, sdk

I'm new to both Java and Android programming and I'm learning fairly quickly, but I can't seem to find any answer to this one after an hour of googling...

I've setup my android app with a preferences.xml that uses a ListPreference entry. It refers to 2 string arrays, one for the list display, the other for the actual values:

```
    <ListPreference
        android:title="Draw Rule"
        android:summary="Choose between Draw 1 and Draw 3"
        android:key="draw_rule"
        android:defaultValue="draw3"
        android:entries="@array/drawrule"
        android:entryValues="@array/drawruleValues" />
```

My arrays.xml looks like this:

```
<string-array name="drawrule">
    <item name="draw1">Draw 1</item>
    <item name="draw3">Draw 3</item>
</string-array>
<string-array name="drawruleValues">
    <item name="draw1">draw1</item>
    <item name="draw3">draw3</item>
</string-array>
```

To get the preferences, I start by using getDefaultSharedPreferences :

```
    SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
```

I understand how to get the correct value from drawruleValues with `sharedPrefs.getString("draw_rule", "null")`. My problem is that for displays purposes I'd like to show the item from drawrule instead, not drawruleValues (e.g. `"Draw Setting: Draw 3"`).

Can anyone tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option #1: Don't use separate `<string-array>` resources. Use `drawrule` for both arrays in your preference definition.

Option #2: Iterate over the contents of `drawruleValues` (via `getStringArray()` on a `Resources` object) to find the index of the value, then use that to get the "title" from the `drawrule` array (again, via `getStringArray()` on a `Resources` object).

Comment: I think Option 1 sounds just about right. As I learn more java and android-specific code, I can probably figure other ways later on. Thanks a bunch!